How does this nested lambda function work?
How do we get the output of 120?
I don't quite understand what is x(y) in the function. Which arguments are passed into which function?
def combinator(y):
  return (lambda x: lambda y: x(y))(lambda x:y)

print(combinator(lambda x: x*10)(11)(12))


x(y) means that argument y is passed into function x.

It looks like this is an exercise where the lambdas and parameter names are deliberately confusing.

What actually happens is that lambda x: x*10 is passed into the function and is returned by calling another lambda with the ignored parameter of 11, and the value 12 is passed in, multiplied by 10 to finally print 120

Lambda functions are very similiar to ordinary def functions but without (directly) assigning them a name. Following definitions are equivalent:
foo = lambda x: y

def foo(x):
    return y

With that, we can convert the code to use standard functions for more clarity.
Let's de-lambdify it step by step:
def combinator(y):
    return (lambda x: lambda y: x(y))(lambda x:y)

Step 1 - (lambda x:y)
def combinator(y):
    def f1(x):
        return y
    return (lambda x: lambda y: x(y))(f1)

It's worth noting here that x in f1 is never referenced. Instead, f1 always returns value of y that combinator was called with (this is where our 11 "disappears" into)
Step 2 - (lambda x: lambda y: x(y))
def combinator(y):
    def f1(x):
        return y
    def f2(x):
        return lambda y: x(y)
    return (f2)(f1)

Step 3 - lambda y: x(y)
(changed names of some variables to show what goes where)
def combinator(y_comb):
    def f1(x1):
        return y_comb
    def f2(x2):
        def f3(y3):
            return x2(y3)
        return f3
    return f2(f1)

Analysing f2 and f3, f2 takes another function x as argument and returns yet another function f3 that will call x with arguments passed to it, making it kind of functional no-op.
Step 4 - combinator(lambda x: x*10)(11)(12)
def f4(x):
    return x*10

print(combinator(f4)(11)(12))

f4 is a very simple function that returns given value * 10
That should make following what's going on much easier.
And PythonTutor link where you can see execution step by step.

This is a great answer, but I think that in Step 3 some of the x and y parameters could be given different names just to show that they are unrelated in the end.

Excellent explanation which shows why the value in (11) is irrelevant and any value would produce the same final result. If the OP pastes the step3 and step 4 code into PythonTutor then the process can be visulaized step-by-step.

Let's explain this by transforming the code.
def combinator(y):
  return (lambda x: lambda y: x(y))(lambda x:y)

print(combinator(lambda x: x*10)(11)(12))

First let's move the parameter lambda to inside the function.
def combinator():
  y = lambda x: x*10
  return (lambda x: lambda y: x(y))(lambda x:y)

print(combinator()(11)(12))

Now let's carefully replace only the y's that are affected.
def combinator():
  return (lambda x: lambda y: x(y))(lambda x:lambda x: x*10)

print(combinator()(11)(12))

That other y doesn't get replaced because it is shadowed by the lambda parameter.
We can now evaluate the call
def combinator():
  return (lambda y: (lambda x:lambda x: x*10)(y))

print(combinator()(11)(12))

This means that combinator returns something that will call the inner function lambda x: lambda x: x*10 with whatever parameter y is supplied. That's the same thing as returning the function itself, but we'll see that when we evaluate without simplifying. Now we can inline the function.
print((lambda y: (lambda x:lambda x: x*10)(y))(11)(12))

The outer x does not replace anything since it's shadowed by the inner x. It's easier to understand if we trivially rename that variable.
print((lambda y: (lambda z:lambda x: x*10)(y))(11)(12))

The 11 gets passed into y,
print(((lambda z:lambda x: x*10)(11))(12))

The z value is discarded, not part of the final computation.
print((lambda x: x*10)(12))

We pass in 12.
print((12*10))

And that produces the answer.
print(120)

